# Youtube-dl - different config file for video & audio?

Tags: youtube-dl

Is it possible to pass a specific config file to `youtube-dl` without writing all
arguments in command line?

Right now I'm using AHK to input in PowerShell for video

```
youtube-dl.exe -o '%(playlist_index)s. %(title)s.%(ext)s' -i -f mp4 --write-sub --sub-lang en --yes-playlist ''
```

and for audio

```
youtube-dl.exe --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 --audio-quality 0 ''
```

Today I wrote the config file in `...Roaming\youtube-dl\config.txt` using
video arguments. But sometimes I want to download only the audio format, sometimes I wonder if there is a way to have `2 config.txt` files one for audio and one for video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I wonder if there is a way to have 2 config.txt files one for audio and one for video?

You can use the `--config-location` option and have 2 different files, for example `video.cfg` and `audio.cfg`. Make sure you specify the full path to the file:

```
--config-location PATH               Location of the configuration file;
                                     either the path to the config or its
                                     containing directory.
```

Source: [youtube-dl/README.md at master · ytdl-org/youtube-dl · GitHub](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#options)